# What is the scope of a public variable?

Tags: java, oop

In a language like Java, the scope of a variable is usually determined by the nearest enclosing braces. (There are syntactic exceptions, such as declarations in the initializer of a `for` loop and the header of a method.) Such variables are not accessible outside of their scope.

What about public instance variables? Static scoping rules would say they are local to the class or object. But they are accessible from outside the class. I am teaching beginning students and the scoping rules for instance variables are not so clear-cut.

As a long-time programmer, the difference is obvious to me. What is a good explanation for a first-year Java student?

Comment: I would say that it's a different conversation/definition than just "variable scope" because the public member is never externally referenced by *just* a variable.  It's a member accessed by dereferencing *another* variable (or reference of some sort, a variable might not be in play at all), and in that context the "scope" of that other variable is what's relevant.  It's not a question of variable scope, it's a question of access modifiers.

Comment: I believe you might not understand the difference between class (instance) and local variables.  Scope of an instance variable is determined strictly by access control modifiers.

Comment: The crucial point here, I think, is that the braces that surround the class body do not constitute a block.

Comment: Just don't try to present Java as something more coherent than it is

Comment: Scope and accessibility aren't the same thing. The scope is the class or an instance, depending on whether it is static or not, as determined by the nearest enclosing `{}` pair, and that is proven by the need to qualify it with the class name or instance when referring to it (other than in derived classes, which have it in scope already).

Answer (score -1):

The public member isn't accessible from anywhere. It's still only accessible within the context of the class instance that contains them, or if static within the context of the class that contains them.

And of course when talking about statics, there's also the ClassLoader in which that class is loaded to be considered, as static scoping does not cause data to be leaked outside the context of a ClassLoader, meaning that 2 Class instances, each contained within its own ClassLoader, do not share their static members.

This allows for 2 ClassLoaders to each have an instance of Class X, one with a static datamember y with value "1" and the other with a static datamember y with value "2".

Normally these would not be visible outside their respective ClassLoaders, but it may be possible to gain access to them in some way (I've never tried, that way lies madness).

Of course ClassLoader issues are generally outside the scope of an introductory programming course :)

And oh, NO members are ever accessible outside their scope. It's just that scopes can vary widely, in sometimes weird ways.

Both private and public members exist within the scope of their containing class instance, unless they're static in which case they exist within the scope of their containing Class (which exists in the context of a specific ClassLoader as mentioned).

Answer (score -2):

Tell them that a public variable is accesible from anywhere in the package

Comment: And anywhere outside it, too.